# How does the "Type" property for files in windows get set?

Tags: windows, file, metadata

If I look at a word document (.docx) or a zip file (.zip) in windows explorer, I see that the type is a nicely presented text string. "Microsoft Word Document" or "Compressed (zipped) Folder".

If I look at a custom file that I have created with a .blah extension, then the type is "BLAH file"

Is there a way to have it say something else in the type? Is it a windows registry thing, or can it be baked in to the file itself

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the default applications for the particular file extension. In the example you have provided try changing the default application of .docx to something like say Notepad. It would change into "DOCX File"